# How to activate a NavigationLink in a List when the row is not yet visible?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-navigationlink

Consider the following view code:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var activeLink: Int? = 45

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Text("Hello, world!")
                    .padding()
                List(0..<100, id: \.self) { i in
                    NavigationLink(
                        tag: i,
                        selection: $activeLink,
                        destination: { MyNextView() }
                    ) {
                        Text("Row nr \(i)")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If the value of `activeLink` is the same as the tag of a NavigationLink that is currently visible in the UI, the NavigationLink will activate and `MyNextView` will be presented as expected. However if `activeLink` has a value equal to a tag of a NavigationLink outside of the visible UI, nothing happens.
This became a problem in my project since I have an `ObservableObject` representing a "routing state"-model in my app that contains the value of every active `NavigationLink` in the view hierarchy. The reason for this is that I want to be able to recreate a view hierarchy on app start. However if my routing state wants to activate a NavigationLink outside of the visible UI, as in the example above, it does not work.

I have tried to scroll the list to the NavigationLink-element I want to activate in order to get it to appear but I have not found a smooth way to do this. I tried using the `ScrollViewProxy.scrollTo(...` in `.onAppear(perform: ...` of my view but it does not work without a `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: ...` which seems very unreliable imo.

Has anyone else come across this problem?

EDIT:
It seems like this is corrected in SwiftUI 4, iOS 16, with NavigationStack(path: ...).

Comment: Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve, edit and format your questions. 

Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot.

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/63849694/12299030?

Comment: Apple have a sample project "Restoring Your App’s State with SwiftUI" that shows how to use onContinueUserActivity to restore the NavigationLink hierarchy. However if more items are added to the sample data and one is selected that is offscreen, on app resume it has the same problem that the link isn't activated.

Comment: @Asperi It seems similar to the hack of putting an empty NavigationLink at the top of the view which is activated when a custom `Binding` activates. This could maybe solve my problem but I have not gotten it to work with restoring the navigation state as of yet. It also adds a lot of complicated boiler plate code that I would like to avoid. But thanks for the tip! If nothing else works I will probably try to do something like this.

Comment: @malhal That's very interesting. I will definitely have a look at the sample project and see if I can learn something. Thanks!

Comment: @malhal As you suggested, the example project has the same issue as I have. Using SceneStorage to save the selected state doesn't seem to make any difference.